# Alternative to C# Dictionary<char, char[]> in Java

Tags: c#, java, dictionary

While rewriting C# class in Java, I would like to know most appropriate alternative to the following,

```
Dictionary<char, char[]> CharMappings = new Dictionary<char,char[]>();
```

I tried several options but none of them seems to be working well. In fact, I do not really understand the Map, HashMap concepts in Java yet. Could not find an abstract alternative to Dictionary so far.

Comment: try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: `HashMap` is equivalent to `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you want the collection to behave you'll have to differentiate between the different types of map, but generally a `HashMap` is what you want.

```
Map<Character, char[]> charMappings = new HashMap<>();
```

Note that you have to use the reference types instead of primitives.

Sample usage:

```
Map<Character, char[]> charMappings = new HashMap<>();

charMappings.put((char) 5, "lola".toCharArray());
System.out.println(charMappings.get((char) 5));
```

Output:

```
lola
```

Comment: `Map<Character, char[]>` would be a closer match, and works since arrays of primitives are reference types.

Comment: @280Z28: Yeah, I was about to edit it but checked with a small codesample first just to be sure.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was going to suggest as well, +1.